# Google Chrome slows on Ajax requests when disconnected

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I am making polling requests to a server using Angulars `$http.post`. However if the server is shutdown, the clients browser (Google Chrome) becomes very slow, on Firefox however it runs fine. I cannot reproduce this on my dev machine, maybe due to it being more powerful, but I did also notice a difference between the two machines. The clients browser reports `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, while mine reports `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I am not sure if this makes any difference.

The code itself does not do much:

```
var update = function () {
    $http.post(url)
        .success(onSuccess)
        .error(onError);
};

var onError = function () {
    $rootScope.errors = true;
    $timeout(update, pollInterval * 2);
};

var onSuccess = function (data) {
    _data = data;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dataUpdated');
    $rootScope.errors = false;
    $timeout(update, pollInterval);
};
```

I cannot find any reason why this would slow down Chrome only on disconnect. Returning a `5xx http code` works fine, so it should not be related to the `onError` function either. Google Chrome version is 33.0.1750.

Comment: The only theory I have is antivirus program interfering somehow. Client is running Trend Micro Officescan.

Comment: Does the app loop through any response data automatically? I had the same problem when my app tried to process through the error messages like they were useful data.

Comment: No, there is no processing done automatically. What is posted is pretty much all that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code waits for the response from the server, and then does stuff given its succeeded or failed. So, that doesn't really point to a performance issue, it just says that things don't happen until you hear back from the server – which takes a lot of time since the server is shut down and its a connection reset (after waiting for a response) rather than an immediate connection refused. Hence the difference.

I'd suggest you use timeouts with your $http when working in a situation where the server might be shut down. [Here's the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).

Answer (score 1):

You should see the settings on the production server... other reason its the clients have an antivirus or anti-spyware.

Also you should manage a timeout on your post petition, 
here an example:

```
var update = function () {
    $http.post(url,null,{ timeout:3000 })
    .success(onSuccess)
    .error(onError);
};
```

Note: This set timeout on 30 seconds.

More parameters here [Arguments for $http object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#usage)

I hope this helps!

Comment: The client does indeed have antivirus software, and I suspect it is the reason. I had not thought of the timeout issue however, I will try it and see if it helps - and award the bounty if it does!

Comment: I suspect this is the closest I will get to an answer, although it has not fully solved the problem, but it was at least helpful!